# Securing with SSL?

Tags: magento

I have tried to secure my magento site with SSL.

I have made all image paths relative and made sure all src data as on the same ip address.

It works perfect in firefox, i get the green padlock, but chrome gives a red line and IE a grey padlock!

Is there any readon why it works on firefox and not the others?

Comment: What type/company did you get the SSL/Cert from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome try to identify issue by pressing **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>** on keyboard.then it will show the bugs appear in your page. Also you can check the issues by clicking on the icon on the top in address bar.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an oldie, but in case it helps someone else. Chrome seems to remember if a site has *ever* sent insecure content during the browser session. So quit/close Chrome and start it up again if it's reporting insecure content when you don't think there is any.